# Import Export Profil in Shopware 6.5 - how to use ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent

Tags: shopware, shopware6

In Shopware 6.4 we created a separate import / export profile for our plugin and used `EntityRepositoryDecorator`.
With Shopware 6.5 there is no longer an `EntityRepositoryDecorator`.
The goal is to change the data of the entity during import before it is written to the database. For this we could use the event `ImportExportBeforeImportRecordEvent`, unfortunately we have no information about which entity is being imported and cannot check this. We cannot execute the code to change the data for each individual entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the entity name from the config provided by the event.

```
public function callbackMethodName $event): void
{
    $entityName = $event->getConfig()->get('sourceEntity');
    // ...
}
```

See [ProductCategoryPathsSubscriber](https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/trunk/src/Core/Content/ImportExport/Event/Subscriber/ProductCategoryPathsSubscriber.php) for an example.